# R - two types of prediction in cross validation

Tags: r, prediction, cross-validation

When i using cross validation technique with my data it gives me two types of prediction. CVpredict and Predict. What is difference between two of that? I guess cvpredict is cross validation predict but what is the other?

Here is some of my code:

```
crossvalpredict <- cv.lm(data = total,form.lm = formula(verim~X4+X4.1),m=5)
```

And this is the result:

```
fold 1 
Observations in test set: 5 
            3    11    15    22    23
Predicted   28.02 32.21 26.53  25.1 21.28
cvpred      20.23 40.69 26.57  34.1 26.06
verim       30.00 31.00 28.00  24.0 20.00
CV residual  9.77 -9.69  1.43 -10.1 -6.06

Sum of squares = 330    Mean square = 66    n = 5 

fold 2 
Observations in test set: 5 
            2     7    21    24    25
Predicted    28.4  32.0  26.2 19.95  25.9
cvpred       52.0  81.8  36.3 14.28  90.1
verim        30.0  33.0  24.0 21.00  24.0
CV residual -22.0 -48.8 -12.3  6.72 -66.1

Sum of squares = 7428    Mean square = 1486    n = 5 

fold 3 
Observations in test set: 5 
            6    14   18    19    20
Predicted   34.48 36.93 19.0 27.79 25.13
cvpred      37.66 44.54 16.7 21.15  7.91
verim       33.00 35.00 18.0 31.00 26.00
CV residual -4.66 -9.54  1.3  9.85 18.09

Sum of squares = 539    Mean square = 108    n = 5 

fold 4 
Observations in test set: 5 
            1     4     5       9   13
Predicted   31.91 29.07  32.5 32.7685 28.9
cvpred      30.05 28.44  54.9 32.0465 11.4
verim       32.00 27.00  31.0 32.0000 30.0
CV residual  1.95 -1.44 -23.9 -0.0465 18.6

Sum of squares = 924    Mean square = 185    n = 5 

fold 5 
Observations in test set: 5 
            8    10    12     16    17
Predicted    27.8 30.28  26.0 27.856 35.14
cvpred       50.3 33.92  45.8 31.347 29.43
verim        28.0 30.00  24.0 31.000 38.00
CV residual -22.3 -3.92 -21.8 -0.347  8.57

Sum of squares = 1065    Mean square = 213    n = 5 

Overall (Sum over all 5 folds) 
 ms 
411
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that by reading the help of the function you are using `cv.lm`. There you will find this paragraph:

> The input data frame is returned, with additional columns
>   ‘Predicted’ (Predicted values using all observations) and ‘cvpred’
>   (cross-validation predictions). The cross-validation residual sum
>   of squares (‘ss’) and degrees of freedom (‘df’) are returned as
>   attributes of the data frame.

Which says that *Predicted* is a vector of predicted values made using all the observations. In other words it seems like a predictions made on your "training" data or made "in sample".

To check wether this is so you can fit the same model using `lm`:

```
fit <- lm(verim~X4+X4.1, data=total)
```

And see if the predicted values from this model:

```
predict(fit)
```

are the same as those returned by `cv.lm`

When I tried it on the *iris* dataset in R - `cv.lm()` predicted returned the same values as `predict(lm)`. So in that case - they are in-sample predictions where the model is fitted and used using the same observations.

Comment: yes it gives same observations. `lm` gives much better results than cross-val. Thanks for the answer. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

lm() does not give "better results." I am not sure how predict() and lm.cv() can be the same. Predict() returns the expected values of Y for each sample, estimated from the fitted model (covariates (X) and their corresponding estimated Beta values). Those Beta values, and the model error (E), were estimated from that original data. By using predict(), you get an overly optimistic estimate of model performance. That is why it seems better. You get a better (more realistic) estimate of model performance using an iterated sample holdout technique, like cross validation (CV). The least biased estimate comes from leave-one-out CV and the estimate with the least uncertainty (prediction error) comes from 2-fold (K=2) CV.

Comment: I understand the former answer that `cv.lm` returns both, standard and cross validated predictions. The remainder of your comment sounds ok.